# Does mongoose allow for multiple database requests concurrently?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read that Mongoose will only open one connection at maximum per collection, and there's no option to change this.

Does this mean that a slow mongo query will make all subsequent queries wait?

I know everything in node.js is non-blocking, but I'm wondering whether a slow query will delay the execution of all subsequent queries. And whether there is a way to change this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It does only use one connection, if you use the default method where you do mongoose.connect(). To get around this, you can create multiple connections, and then tie a model pointing to the same schema to that connection.

Like so:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test');
var conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test');
var model1 = conn.model('Model', Schema);
var model2 = conn2.model('Model', Schema);
model1.find({long query}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out last");
});
model2.find({short query}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out first");
});
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**
Hey, that does work. Updating from the comments, you can create a connection pool using createConnection. It lets you do multiple queries from the same model concurrently:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test', {server:{poolSize:2}});
var model = conn.model('Model', Schema);
model.find({long query}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out last");
});
model.find({short query}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out first");
});
```

**Update 2 -- Dec 2012**
This answer may be slightly outdated now--I noticed I've been continuing to get upvotes, so I thought I would update it. The mongodb-native driver that mongoose wraps now has a default connection pool size of 5, so you probably don't need to explicitly specify it in mongoose.

Comment: I understand it uses only one connection, but what happens when I use just one connection and a mongodb query immediately follows another heavy mongodb query? Will the first query I mention wait until the second query I mention finishes its work on mongodb?

Comment: Aha, I guess you're telling me it will wait, and hence I should use a different model. I see, thanks.

Comment: Yep. If you try it with just one connection, they will print in the order queried.

Comment: Ok, but shoudn't it be the responsibility of Mongoose to maintain a connection pool to avoid such issues? I know some other Mongoose libraries do that, and this makes me wonder whether I made a good choice with Mongoose.

Comment: Thanks @k00k, I actually ran a test and then retyped it with more generic names, with that typo in it. You're right, should have been conn2.

Comment: I agree, a lot of the other mongodb libraries manage connections for you. The official driver does support connection pools. I guess it's a price to pay for mongoose model/middleware convenience. (And you can work around it if you need to).

Comment: @WesFreeman Here it says that connection pooling is possible in Mongoose: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongoose-orm/NHqZOjMg-Ng - specifically:    [...] how do I create multiple connections (or create a pool of them beforehand)? `mongoose.createConnection(uri, { server: { poolSize: N }});`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that. Just tested with my test code that has a long and short query, and it does work. poolSize of 1 gives the old behavior where it waits for "long query" to finish.

Comment: You can use mongeese https://github.com/donpark/mongeese for multiple instances of mongoose object ( e.g. several connections )

Comment: Thanks @WesFreeman - quick last question: how do I create a "long query" in mongodb, so that I can do my tests as well?

Comment: Well, make a test database of a million rows at least, and then run a query that sorts on a non-indexed field. That's what I did, anyway. I already had my logging data there (so I didn't need to make a test database), which has millions of rows--the query in question took on the order of 30 seconds for me. Just posted some examples on http://wes.skeweredrook.com/testing-with-mongodb-part-1/