# How to handle two different connections to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working currently with one NodeJS + Express + Mongodb Applicacion and I need to get information stored in another monogodb database. So in my app.js file I'm doing the following steps in my app: 
    app.js

```
var session         = require('express-session');
var MongoStore      = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var passport        = require('passport');

var configDB        = require('./config/database.js'); 
// here I get the info from the Database IP and port.
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
app.use( session({store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection:                mongoose.connections[0]}),
    secret: 'secretPass',
    cookie: {maxAge: 36000}, // session secret
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true}
));
```

Is there a way to add another connection so I can use it so get information stored in the second database?

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039163/does-mongoose-allow-for-multiple-database-requests-concurrently

Comment: Thanks  Anand S, this was helpfull. I can connect to both databases this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database1'); // database connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database2');
```